# Top.gg Webhook URL

Tags: python, webhooks

What do I enter here as my webhook url? This is for my discord bot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Webhook URL" field is for rewarding an user for voting for your Discord bot. If you have a web server for your Discord bot that you use for validating votes and/or rewarding users, you're supposed to put the link to that server there to receive the voting events. If you don't have a web server and don't want to reward the users who vote, you can leave it blank.